# While starting emulator, How to avoid Process System is not responding. WAIT/OK WVGA800 API level 15

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Problem: I start emulator with WVGA800 Skin, and is alwasys showing "Process system is not responding   " message  and asks to "Would you like to close it?  Wait/OK"?

Description:
I created avd from AVD manager in Windows Centrino Duo machine with 2GB RAM.
Android emulators starting from ver 1.6 to 2.3.3 are starting good. I have been using api level 13,10,8,11,4, but I never faced the issue.

But I am able to deploy and work with applications like hello world, viewflipper with hyper link text.

One of the application using webservices fails while invoking webservice which works in earlier version of emulators.

Comment: I am still ignoring this issue and continuing with emulator.  Note  sure the probem with emulator on Windows machine. I hope Google will address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the ICS Intel x86 image.  You can find it [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-ice-cream-sandwich-x86-emulator-image/).

Comment: Thank your Dirk Jackel for your response. I have been using the same based on the information @ http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html   But let me please investing on this and post my comments.  Once again thanks.

Comment: While creating AVD for Motorola ICS R1, it's not allow to use modern emulator.   Your response reminded me that I should select the "intelx86 image" option from the drop down while creating AVD.